# The code in UrlRoutingModule crashed

Tags: ithit-webdav-server

When debugging my code, several times the code in the UrlRoutingModule class crashed. There are 2 kinds of error:

- Null reference exception:

`foreach (var route in l)
    {
       RouteTable.Routes.Add(route);   <-- It crashed here because route is NULL
    }`

I added "if (route != null)" before the above statement and it seemed to fix the problem.

- ArgumentException: The route provided already exists in the route collection. The collection may not contain duplicate routes.

The second exception also happened at the same line as above.

What can I do to fix this issue because as soon as this error happened, I had to close IIS Express and Visual Studio because the whole site got hosed.

Comment: It looks like a bug in IT Hit WebDAV Server sample code generated by the WebDAV wizard when used with MVC project in Visual Studio 2013. We are looking into this issue. With Visual Studio 2012 and earlier as well as with other types of projects in VS 2013 it is working with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in UrlRoutingModule class. It is fixed in in the latest build that we have published today. Here is the correct implementation of this class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Forbids MVC routing of WebDAV requests that should be processed by WebDAV handler.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This module is needed for ASP.NET MVC application to forbid routing
/// of WebDAV requests that should be processed by <see cref="DavHandler"/>.
/// It reads DavLocations section and inserts ignore rules for urls that correspond
/// to these locations.
/// </remarks>
public class UrlRoutingModule : IHttpModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents route to be ignored. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Required to insert ignore route at the beginning of routing table. We can not 
    /// use the <see cref="RouteCollection.IgnoreRoute"/> as it adds to the and of the 
    /// routing table.
    /// </remarks>
    private sealed class IgnoreRoute : Route
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates ignore route.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">Route to be ignored.</param>
        public IgnoreRoute(string url)
            : base(url, new StopRoutingHandler())
        {
        }
        public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that the web application is started.
    /// </summary>
    private static bool appStarted = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Application start lock.
    /// </summary>
    private static object appStartLock = new Object();

    void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        // Here we update ASP.NET MVC routing table to avoid processing of WebDAV requests.
        // This should be done only one time during web application start event.

        lock (appStartLock)
        {
            if (appStarted)
            {
                return;
            }
            appStarted = true;
        }

        DavLocationsSection davLocationsSection = DavLocationsSection.Instance;

        int routeInsertPosition = 0;
        foreach (DavLocation location in davLocationsSection.Locations)
        {
            string[] methods = location.Verbs.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(verb => verb.Trim().ToUpper()).ToArray();

            string prefix = location.Path.Trim(new[] { '/', '\\' });
            string path = (prefix == string.Empty ? string.Empty : prefix + "/") + "{*rest}";

            IgnoreRoute ignoreRoute = new IgnoreRoute(path);
            if (methods.Length > 0)
            {
                ignoreRoute.Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary { { "httpMethod", new HttpMethodConstraint(methods) } };
            }
            RouteTable.Routes.Insert(routeInsertPosition++, ignoreRoute);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```